# Rails 3: Proper way to Delete resource using respond_with

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actioncontroller, respond-with

I'm trying to DRY up a controller by incorporating `respond_with`. When I do, following some instructions in a Railscast, I get things *mostly* working. The problem lies in the redirect after **deleting** a resource...which should be redirecting to `people_url`...but instead tries to load the specific resource.

The sample code I found looks like this...But it fails trying to load the resource it just deleted:

```
# app/controllers/people_controller.rb
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml

  def destroy
    @person = Person.find(params[:id])
    flash[:notice] = 'Successfully deleted person.' if @person.destroy
    respond_with(@person)  # <== spec fails here
  end
end
```

changing that last line to `respond_with(@people)` doesn't work either (though I had hoped it would...)

After much digging around and trying my best to understand things I did get things to work (at least it would appear so. specs passing. app functional) with this:

```
respond_with(@person, :location => people_url)  # <== now it works
```

So, is this the correct way to handle this? It seems that with all the 'magic' behind respond_with it would know it can't redirect to itself after a delete? I also figured this (one of 7 basic RESTful CRUD methods) would be pretty basic and rudimentary so plenty of examples would abound...but I haven't been able to find many except the ones suggesting the code that didn't work for me.

Hoping someone can help me understand the rails 'magic' that is occurring here so I won't be surprised when this blows up on me down the road.

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to respond with a resource that's deleted. That's what the problem is. In cases such as deletion, header-only responses work. Setting the request header status to `:ok` is enough.

```
head :ok
```

Comment: Thank you but, sadly, i'm still confused. are you suggesting `respond_with(head :ok)`? because that doesn't work. I'm only familiar with `format.xml { head :ok }` when inside a `respond_to` block. so not sure how to work it in using `respond_with` in this case?!?

Comment: @Meltemi - Check out the ASCIICast from Ryan Bates: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/224-controllers-in-rails-3